# I'm trying to take the output of a console function and put it into an alert

Tags: javascript, console

So, I've been trying to take the output of the console and put it into an `alert()`. The code that I have been using is as follows, `var d = "x"; console.log(d);`. Then I get stuck because I do not know how to take the output of the `console.log()`.

Comment: Are you trying to print the variable "d" in alert? If so, what's the problem in it?

Comment: `alert(d)` ? If you are trying to "output" the interactive debugging info (inspection etc) that most browsers console provide, you are out of luck

Comment: if you just need to halt your execution, just use `console.log(d); debugger;`.

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain your use case in more detail

Comment: console.log vs alert

alert method
its used to show some message is popup. 
It block javascript execution until “OK” button clicked

console.log method
Its of developer oriented
It allows you to view more detailed object hierarchy which is not possible by alert(because it was not made it).

Comment: @MarianTheisen Yes, I was trying to output the debugging info (I just couldn't think of how to say that). Thank you, that helped a lot. I will keep this in mind the next time I ask a question so that I can do better asking.

Answer (score 0):

console.log just prints to console, if you want to show the same in an alert window, just do alert

```
 var d = "x"; 
 //console.log(d);
 alert(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the console.log function with a function that alert the input.

```js
    console.log = function(text){
        alert(text);
    }
```